# Como ordenar lista de tuplas em python pelo valor

Tags: python, python-3.x

Como ordenar uma lista de tuplas, pelo valor. Por exemplo:

```
x=[{"nome":1},{"data":4},{"dia":5}]
```

Gostaria que ficasse:

```
x=[{"dia":5},{"data":4},{"nome":1}]
```

Comment: Obs.: você possui uma lista de dicionários, não de tuplas.

Comment: oi raiza, por favor coloque o código das tentativas que você fez e ao invés de perguntar como fazer pergunte o que você esta fazendo de errado após tentar, dê uma olhada também no [tour] da plataforma assim voce vai ficar inteirada de como escrever uma pergunta :)

Answer (score 0):

Bem vinda ao [Stack Overflow](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/)! Primeiro de tudo, o que você tem não é uma lista de tuplas e sim, uma lista de dicionários. Uma lista de tuplas seria isto:

```
lista = [('dia',5),('data',4),('nome',1)]
```

Agora que entendemos isso, a forma mais fácil de organizar essa lista é utilizando o método `sort` passando para o parâmetro `key` uma função que possua um parâmetro chamado "key" onde será passado cada item da lista e essa função deve retornar um valor.

O valor de retorno será comparado com os outros valores obtidos e a lista será organizada com base nesses valores na ordem decrescente. É por isso até que o nome do parâmetro se chama "key", porque o retorno da função não será um valor a ser inserido na lista, e sim a "chave" do mesmo. Exemplo:

```
def organiza(key):
    if key%2 == 0: key += 2
    return key
lista = [1,2,3,4]
lista.sort(key=organiza)
print(lista)
```

A saída será: `[1, 3, 2, 4]`

Isto aconteceu porque lá na função `organiza`, eu disse para o Python somar `+2` para todo valor que fosse **par**. Logo a chave de **3** seria **3** e a chave de **2** seria **4**. Como o número três é menor que quatro, o valor `3` fica na frente do `2` na lista.